# How to custom colour ASP.NET treeview selectednodestyle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I would like to colour my selectednode with custom color, when i select node by default id becomes red, now this is the problem, I created 2 css classes:

```
.NodoSelNormale
{
    color: Yellow;
}

.NodoSelPS
{
    color: #e2cfa8;
}
```

In the page_load I've inserted the c# code:

```
            if (Advsecu.GetCurrentUserLevel().ToString() == "8")
            {              
                treeDir.SelectedNodeStyle.CssClass = "NodoSelPS";             
            }
            else
            {
                treeDir.SelectedNodeStyle.CssClass = "NodoSelNormale";
            }
```

When I select a node it becomes RED the code it's not working, I've inserted in any event listener like selectednodechenged, selectednodechanging,  treenodechecked, treenodechanged it isn't working, why ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` rule to color style in `NodoSelNormale` and `NodoSelPS` css classes.

By the way, in question title you mentioning GridView, but in question mention treenodechecked event. Which one control you are use?

Comment: it's not working, it still remains red, but when i call command:
treeDir.nodes[2].selected = true; 
it becomes Yellow, and if I change node it remain yellow and others change in Red